# How to enter a password to a password protected key file from Command prompt?

Tags: command-line, command, command-prompt

I need to checkout a project from SVN, but every time I open the project, Visual Studio 2017 asks me to enter a password to a key file. The password is to access to assembly files. I've found a manually workaround, but I need to do this as a **command line** with command Prompt. Someone know how ? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to *checkout* a project, you don't need to open an existing one. Just checkout a new one.

Visual Studio 2017 does not have built-in support for SVN. SVN integrates with Visual Studio via extensions such as VisualSVN or AnkhSVN. Therefore, it is not quite clear what and when exactly prompts for password. Most likely, that prompt is not related to SVN.

Comment: It's not a password about SVN, but to access to assembly files.

Comment: @Emile you may want to include this into your question's body and maybe retag it a bit.